# React Form Component onSubmit Handler Not Working

Tags: reactjs

I have the following React component:

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let loginInput = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.login);

    // change Main component's state
    this.props.addCard(loginInput.value);

    // reset the form
    loginInput.value = '';
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input placeholder="githug login" ref="login" />
        <button>Add Login</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I want the `handleSubmit` function to be called whenever the form is submitted. I have indicated this by adding the function to the `onSubmit` handler.

The function is being invoked at the correct time. However, the value of `this` within that function is `null`. This is surprising to me, as I expected the value of `this` to be the React Component. The fact that `this` is null is surprising to me, because I am using a very similar logic / code as suggest by the [official React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

I would appreciate the help in figuring out why `this` is not the React component, as expected, and how to fix the code so that it is.

Comment: http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/refactoring-react-components-to-es6-classes --- see step #3 or https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding or http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you use `React` with [`ES2015 classes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) you should set `this` to event handlers

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }    

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let loginInput = this.refs.login;
    this.props.addCard(loginInput.value);
    loginInput.value = '';
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
        <input placeholder="githug login" ref="login" />
        <button>Add Login</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/29486/)

> [`No Autobinding`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding)
>
> Methods follow the same semantics as regular ES6 classes, meaning that
>   they don't automatically bind this to the instance. You'll have to
>   explicitly use .bind(this) or arrow functions =>.

Comment: For me it was binding issue `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);`

Comment: If you use hooks, this wouldn't be an issue ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Answer (score 23):

You need to use `button` or `input` with `type="submit"`

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Or

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Extra information: Submitting the form programmatically didn't call the `onSubmit` callback. Adding a `buttton` with `type="submit"` worked.

Comment: Yes thats the HTML5 form behaviour

Answer (score 11):

One obvious piece of information: do not forget to include your button inside the `<form>`.
I got stuck for a while until I figured out I had put my submit button *outside* my form, like this:

```
  <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
    <input placeholder="githug login" ref="login" />
  </form>            
  <button type="submit">Add Login</button>
```

hence the onSubmit event was not being called, and would never be.

Answer (score 5):

For me, it was because the form didn't have an `action` property set.

```html
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} action="#">
    <input placeholder="githug login" ref="login" />
    <button>Add Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me with a submit handler that just pushed a new location onto the history. Submitting my form would refresh the page, leaving me at the old location. I fixed that with `event.preventDefault()` at the start of my submit handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using functional component then make sure your button has a type "Submit" and not "button". This is what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

As @Bernat mentionned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56018303/6824121).

> Extra information: Submitting the form programmatically didn't call
> the `onSubmit` callback. Adding a `button` with `type="submit"`
> worked.

Which means that this code will not trigger the onSubmit function:

```
class Form extends React.Component {

    submitProgrammatically() {
        const element = document.querySelector(`form`);
        element.submit(); // <-- will NOT trigger onSubmit
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <form onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
            }}>
                <input placeholder="githug login" ref="login" />
                <button type="submit">Add Login</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

While this code will trigger `onSubmit`

```
class Form extends React.Component {

    submitProgrammatically() {
        const element = document.querySelector(`form button[type='submit']`);
        element.click(); // <-- will trigger handleSubmit
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <form onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
            }}>
                <input placeholder="githug login" ref="login" />
                <button type="submit">Add Login</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```