# ReactJs form onSubmit handle not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a ReactJs component. handleSubmit is not called when my form is submitted. I am using meteorJs as my backend and ReactJs as my frontend library. I don't know where is the problem. I tried commenting out everything except input tag but didn't work.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class ConfessionPoster extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value: ''
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
}

//handle form submit
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("We are in handle");
    console.log(this.state.value);
}

handleInputChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // const target = event.target;
    // const confessionValue = target.value;
    // const confessionName = target.name;
    //
    // this.setState({[confessionName]: confessionValue});
    // console.log(this.state.confessionText);

    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    console.log(this.state.value);
}

render() {
    return (

        <div id="confession-poster" className="modal">

            <div className="modal-content">

                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s1">
                        <i className="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col s11">
                        <h6>Kiran Kumar Chaudhary</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                    <div className="row confession-area">

                        <div className="input-field col s12">
                            <label htmlFor="confession-textarea">Your Confession</label>
                            <textarea id="confession-textarea" className="materialize-textarea" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div className="row">

                        <div className="col s12">
                            <i className="material-icons">photo_camera</i>&nbsp;
                            <i className="material-icons">link</i>&nbsp;
                            <i className="material-icons">location_on</i>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div className="row">

                        <div className="input-field col s12">
                            <input type="checkbox" className="filled-in" id="hide-my-identity" defaultChecked/>
                            <label htmlFor="hide-my-identity">Hide my Identity</label>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div className="row">
                        <input className="btn" type="submit" value="Post"/>
                    </div>

                </form>

            </div>

        </div>

    );
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Form Component onSubmit Handler Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098324/react-form-component-onsubmit-handler-not-working)

Comment: i think issue is somewhere else because this code is working, check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wq9tp0cm/

Comment: I tried that too but does not work.

Comment: @MayankShukla I am using materializecss as my css framework and this component is the model. I am only using ReactJs as frontend framework. How can I debug this issue now?

Comment: any errors on console? @kiran

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the part of the code you included. When I try this code out, it works for me ( I get the correct logs from the function)

Comment: @nabn No any log in console when form is submitted. It is working in JsFiddle but not working in the project.

Comment: I think we need more context here. @kiran

Comment: I am using meteorJs javascript framework and reactJs as frontend library. @nabn

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about meteor framework. What you should be certain is this part of the code works. So think about what else could be the problem: anything leading to this, or anything that happens after this.